# realmId doesn't come from QBO through the OpenId workflow

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We are trying to implement OpenId in our application to connect to QBO. As an example we use code supplied by Intuit

https://code.intuit.com/integration/viewvc/viewvc.cgi/IntuitAnywhere-.NET/HelloIntuitAnywhere/HelloIntuitAnywhere/OpenIdHandler.aspx.cs?root=intuitanywhere&system=exsy1003&view=markup

The problem is that realmId is null, basically it doesn't come from the Intuit login page back to our app. All other data comes OK like Name, email.

We define attribute as

```
fetch.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(
    "http://axschema.org/intuit/realmId", true, 1));
```

I read that it was in bug in Intuit with regards to setting some cookies. Is it a problem or I am just doing something wrong?

I can post more code if need, but it's pretty much as in example supplied by Intuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the customer authorizes access to their data through the 3 legged Oauth flow, the realmid will be on the querystring of the call back url that you provide.

The openId workflow doesnt always result in a customer selecting a QuickBooks company.

After the openid flow, call the javascript function direct connect(), you will get the realm id in the oauth flow as mentioned above

thanks